# How to connect and push project to gitserver

Tags: git

I'm newer on using git.

My boss gave me a link git-server like that: `//Dev/.../ios_project.git` and asked me to push my project on it (not push on GitHub, but company server).

After reading the documentation on git-scm.com I'm still confused and have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to `push` code to your git server you need to do the following:

1. Add your files which you wish to upload to your server
2. commit the changes (with a commit message)
3. Add the remote server url
4. push the code (upload) to your server

---

```
# Track your local changes
git status

# Add the desired files (Choose the suitable one for you)
git add <file name> <file name> <file name>

# Add all files in a given folder
git add <folder name>

# Add all files
git add .

# Add the remote
git remote add origin <url>

# "upload" your files to your server
git push origin <branch name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: `//Dev/.../ios_project.git` that link will work only if your working repo is placed on same machine with bare (your Dev repo) or if you will mount it directory to your local machine. Else link to repo must start with `protocol@ip:` like 'git@xx.xx.xx.xx:/dev/typesetting.git` and if you public key is writen in .ssh/authorized_keys on remote host your pushes will be accepted, else you will must to enter the password.

1) You need to add repository that your boss give you like a remote repository:

```
git remote add <choose the name of host like prod or dev> //Dev/.../ios_project.git
```

2) You need to add files that you want to push (or just commit) to stage

```
git add <file1> <file2> 
// or to add all changed and new files 
git add .
```

3) To fix phase of your work

```
git commit -m 'litle explanation of current changes'
```

4) after all just push it

```
git push <name of remote host that you set earlier> <branch to push (like dev for egx.)>
```